# Testing preConfirm hook of SweetAlert2 in a React module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs, sweetalert2

Having a React module name `Modal` as such:

```
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content'

export const Modal = withReactContent(Swal)
const showModal = props => {
  return Modal.fire({
    ...props,
    showCloseButton: true
  })
}

export default showModal
```

Which is being used in another component as a confirm box for a user action

```
export const renderDeployModal = (deploymentId) => {
  console.log(' - renderDeployModal - ')
  Modal.fire({
    type: 'question',
    text: `Are you sure you wish to re-deploy this (${deploymentId})?`,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Deploy',
    preConfirm: () => {
      console.log(' - preConfirm - ')
      return apiRequest(`/deployments/${deploymentId}/trigger`, {}, 'POST')
        .then(response => {
          return response.body
        })
        .catch(response => {
          Modal.showValidationMessage(response.message)
        })
    },
    allowOutsideClick: () => !Modal.isLoading()
  }).then(result => {
    if (result.value) {
      notify('success', 'Your deployment has triggered.')
    }
  })
}
```

The implementation works, but where I am stuck is with testing the logic that executes in `preConfirm` hook, because I cannot figure any way to trigger the `Modal.clickConfirm()` manually in my tests and actually work

```
import * as mockModal from '../../modal'
jest.mock('../../modal')

describe('renderDeployModal', () => {

  it('fails to run a deploy without deploymentId argument', async () => {
    const Modal = mockModal.Modal.mockImplementationOnce()

    Modal.fire.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ value: false }))
    Modal.clickConfirm = jest.fn()

    // Modal.clickConfirm.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve())
    // const spy = jest.spyOn(mockModal.Modal, 'clickConfirm')

    apiRequest.default = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.reject(new Error('foo')))
    await renderDeployModal(null)
    await Promise.resolve()

    Modal.clickConfirm()
    await Promise.resolve()

    expect(Modal.fire).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(Modal.clickConfirm).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(apiRequest.default).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`/deployments/null/trigger`, {}, 'POST')
  })
```

The test above fails at the last expected for `apiRequest`.

```
  console.log src/actions.js:111
     - renderDeployModal -
 FAIL  src/actions.test.js
...
    ✕ fails to run a deploy without deploymentId argument (56ms)

  ● renderDeployModal › fails to run a deploy without deploymentId argument

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

    Expected mock function to have been called with:
      ["/deployments/null/trigger", {}, "POST"]
    But it was not called.

      148 |     expect(Modal.fire).toHaveBeenCalled()
      149 |     expect(Modal.clickConfirm).toHaveBeenCalled()
    > 150 |     expect(apiRequest.default).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`/deployments/null/trigger`, {}, 'POST')
          |                                ^
```

Also `console.log(' - renderDeployModal - ')` shows up, but `console.log(' - preConfirm - ')` doesn't, indicating `Modal.clickConfirm()` is not triggering correctly.

What am I missing here? I am out of ideas (good or bad) to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you mock a module as you have

```
jest.mock('../../modal')
```

it creates mock function for each property of the module object object without implementation.

So you're passing an object to `Modal.fire()`, which has the callback `preConfirm`, but there's nothing that's supposed to be calling it. So you should probably change the mock implementation to something like:

```
Modal.fire.mockImplementationOnce(({ preConfirm }) => {
  preConfirm(); // <- execute the given callback
  return Promise.resolve({ value: false })
})
```

and then expect it to have been called

---

**side note:** and by the way there's no point of

```
test('if I call a function it`s actually being called', () => {
    Modal.clickConfirm() // <- execute a function within the test
    expect(Modal.clickConfirm).toHaveBeenCalled() // and make sure it have been called few lines below
});
```

Comment: Gotcha! Brilliant and elegant solution.